# Google Cloud Functions PubSub Data to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I want to stream MQTT sensor data to Google BigQuery via a Google Cloud Function PubSub Tigger. Somehow I can't import BigQuery ...
const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/bigquery'

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us some more details?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the package in package.json dependencies file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "0.10.0",
     ...
}
```

Here is an example in nodejs [Cloud Function using Bigquery](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/functions/sendgrid)